# Syntax error while trying to update some column of a table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have written a C# code to update some column of a table of SQL server. Name of Table is "finalfee". When i am trying to execute the code it is showing syntax error. Why is it happening?

```
SqlConnection con23 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                    con23.Open();    
SqlCommand cmd10 = new SqlCommand("update finalfee SET amountpaid='" + t26 + "',discountamount='" + t30 + "',grandamount='" + t27 + "',balanceamount='"+t28+"' where admno='"+TextBox56.Text+"')", con23);
                        cmd10.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the last ')' in your Command.

```
SqlCommand cmd10 = new SqlCommand("update finalfee SET amountpaid='" + t26 + "',discountamount='" + t30 + "',grandamount='" + t27 + "',balanceamount='"+t28+"' where admno='"+TextBox56.Text+"'", con23);
```

You Should be using Parameters.

Edit:

remove the ')' here: admno='"+TextBox56.Text+"'**)**"

Comment: Which one i have to remove i am not getting you

Comment: No problem. Consider using parameters to prevent Sql Injection.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection con23 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                    con23.Open();    
SqlCommand cmd10 = new SqlCommand("update finalfee SET amountpaid='" + t26 + "',discountamount='" + t30 + "',grandamount='" + t27 + "',balanceamount='"+t28+"' where admno='"+TextBox56.Text+"'", con23);
                        cmd10.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a closing parenthesis without opening one. **+"')"**

Creating a command by joining strings can create many problems. Consider using command parameters.

[SQLCommand Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)